# Has Spidey ever made a quip that cost someone a life?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, spider-man, avengers-vs-x-men

In the new Avengers Vs X-Men #1 comic, Spider-Man creates a prodigious amount of webbing to save people falling from the sky. He makes a quip, as he is want to do:

> Aaaand you're welcome.
>
> Those are official Spider-Man spider-webs, by the way.
>
> Not sold in stores.

In the mean time Ms Marvel is *catching the tip of the Empire State Building*, Iron Man is *vapourising an airplane wing* and Thor is *catching a failing plane in a hurricane he just created*.

It got me thinking, has Spider-Man ever made a quip that wasted time in such a way that lost someone their life?

Comment: Talking is a free action.

Comment: It's a swift, and only one of those per turn

Comment: Marvel Comics has a history of characters somehow squeezing in multi-sentence monologues between throwing a punch and landing it. Spidey benefits from this effect as much as anyone.

Answer (score 3):

One situation came into my mind: That one scene in the 2002 Spider-Man movie where he lets (the future) Sandman escape due to not receiving his money, leading to Uncle Ben's death. Although he didn't talk the exact second Ben is attacked, it still leads to his death.

Comment: The Reboot movie or the latest movie? I'm a bit confused as to which movie you mean.

Comment: The first of the trilogy - not the one from the 70's. :) Is there a new one in the making?

Comment: Yes there is. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

He said

> "Not my problem."

when he allowed the crook that would later kill Uncle Ben to run.

Comment: That's deliberate in action, not time wasting to crack a joke. Good try though.